# Have I to allocate memory before using this system calls?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, free, system-calls

I always see this functions called without allocate memory for `path`, `dir`, `buf` and `name`.

```
char *getcwd(char *path, size_t size);

struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dir);

int stat(const char *file_name, struct stat *buf);

DIR *opendir(const char *name);
```

Why? Do the functions allocate memory? Have I to use free() after using them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They are just pseudo-code examples.  They aren't going to show you how to allocate memory for them for you, it's assumed you know how to do that.

And yes, you need to free all the memory you allocate, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

All your examples take pointers, so indicate they operate on memory you have allocated, not that they allocate it for you.

Comment: I don't understand why without allocate memory they work.
@Sandro 's answer tells about a malloc using by `getcwd()`

Comment: He deleted the answer :S

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code  in which getcwd, readdir stat and opendir called without allocating memory?

Usually some lib/system calls expect you to pass a valid address it can be malloc'd or memory from stack.

For example

char file_name[]="test";
struct stat buf;

stat(file_name, &buf);

-> here buf is passed as call-by a reference so kernel can just fill the need info.

Here we pass memory from stack.

There are few API's which can allocate memory on this own using malloc and return the pointer to you. And you have to free that memory once u r done with that.

example:   strdup

Go through the man pages for more details on each call.